# How to load XLSX files into MySQL (without converting to CSV)?

Tags: mysql, excel, mysql-workbench, xlsx

I have 20 XLSX (Excel 2013) files I need to import into a MySQL database. I am looking for a script to bulk import these files.

Examples I have found suggest converting the XLS or XLSX into CSV. I could also use MySQL for Excel.

However both these approaches are manual and would need to be repeated 20 times. I am looking for a MySQL script I can apply to bulk import.

Can the below code be modified to work on XLSX files?

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/file.txt' 
INTO TABLE tablename 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

I have already created the table structure in my SQL database. Ideally this can all be done via MySQL Workbench.

Comment: No, it can't. But it's not too complex to use i.e. VBA to create CSV files from a list of valid excel filenames in a target directory. Then script the importing of csv files from a directory and you're done.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid the additional step of converting to CSV however if there is no functionality or third party plug in I guess I have no choice.

Comment: While I don't know if there is an import software for MySQL you could use ADO/DAO and create a connection to the MySQL server and read in the Excel workbooks (Excel is a valid data source for ADO/DAO).

Comment: An application I wrote http://excel2mysql.net will handle your data easily and quickly and most importantly with 100% accuracy.  Trust me, depending on the size and complexity of your data, there are many pitfalls to successfully and accurately converting.